# Iframe to other web side

Tags: php, html, iframe, href

I cannot go to other website located in different domains.

```
echo "<b>Enter your page:</b> <br>  
<form action='iframe.php' method='get'>
      <input type='text' name='www' size='50' value='https://'> 
      <input type='submit' value='Go to!'>
</form>
<br>"; 

echo "<iframe width='80%' height='80%' src=" ;

if(!isset($_GET['www'])){
       echo "www.google.com>";
}
else{
       echo "".$_GET['www'].">";  
}
```

Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Your question is not clear. By the way, It seems like you're trying to navigate within `iframe`, which should be done using JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend using `iframe` (which, in my opinion, is a very ugly), but I've tested the following code (JavaScript, HTML & PHP) and it seems to work. In your original code you've reffered to google without any `http` or `https` prefix, but when I've tested it (for another website) it seemed to work.

Anyway, you might want to try my way:

**PHP**:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['www'])) {
        $url = $_GET['www'];
    } else {
        $url = 'https://www.google.com/';
    }
?>
```

**HTML**:

```
<strong>Enter URL:</strong>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="www" size="50" placeholder="https or http" />
    <button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
<iframe style="width: 80%; height: 80%;" id="iframe"></iframe>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
var url   = '<?php echo $url; ?>';
var frame = document.getElementById('iframe');

iframe.src = url;
```

Simply combine all of them in one page (JS inside a `script` tag just before the body closure) and try to access any other website (which isn't `google.com`). It should work for you.

**Do not forget** - Always validate and sanitize your input from XSS and other possible vulnerabilities.